# SWT Tree and TreeItem: Remove or change the drawing behavior of the expand/collapse indicator

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, drawing, swt

I'm working in SWT (no JFace), and I'm attempting to customize the behavior of a Tree that I'm using a sidebar.

The top-level items in the tree shouldn't be selectable; they're basically headers.  Only the children of these items should be selectable.  As a result, I would like the UI to behave in a way that indicates this; clicking on one of these top-level items should expand or collapse but shouldn't provide any sort of visual feedback outside of the indicator changing its state and the children's visibility changing.

The problem seems to be that on OS X, the expand/collapse indicator is a triangle (don't know if it's an image or a unicode character) that either points right or down, but is also colored based on the "selection" state.  I've managed to override all of the relevant behavior for the top-level items except for the arrow changing color.

- I've used an `SWT.EraseItem` listener to hook in to the background drawing so that the background doesn't change color.  This works as expected.
- I've used an `SWT.PaintItem` listener to make sure that the text in the top-level item doesn't change color.  This works as expected, but doesn't seem to have any influence over the indicator; I've even tried *not* resetting the GC's foreground color, but the color of the indicator still changes:

**Not Selected**:

[image: Not Selected]

**Selected**

[image: Selected and Ugly]

Some of the things that I've attempted to do, all of which have failed:

- Just drawing a rectangle on top of indicator.  The indicator seems to always be on top, no matter what I attach the PaintListener to.
- Using a Listener on the Selection event type, checking to see if the `event.item` is one of the top-level items, and then fiddling with the event bits and redraw flags.  This doesn't seem to work well at all; the behavior is completely unpredictable.  The code looks something like this:

  ```
  sideBar.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
  {
      @Override
      public void handleEvent(Event event)
      {
          TreeItem eventItem = (TreeItem) event.item;

          if(sideBarRoots.contains(event.item))
          {
              event.detail = 0;
              event.type = 0;
              event.doit = false;
              sideBar.setRedraw(false);
          }
          else
          {
              sideBar.setRedraw(true);
              event.type = SWT.Selection;
              event.doit = true;
          }
      }
  });
  ```

  Since the redraw flag is just a hint, sometimes it gets set properly and others it doesn't.  It can have either no effect, or can get locked in to a state where nothing redraws in the sidebar.

I'm aware that a lot of this behavior is highly coupled to the behavior of the underlying native widgets, but I was wondering if there was any way to get the behavior that I'm looking for without roll a custom widget from scratch?

Comment: Have you tried running your app on a different OS just to see how it looks? My guess would be that you can't do much about the arrows since they are handled by the OS.

Comment: @Baz no, but IIRC on Windows they use a "plus/minus" image inside of a little box so the behavior is totally different.  I'm thinking I'm going to have to roll my own widget, something built out of Lists and Labels with custom drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in a situation as yours you should ideally not allow selection on a tree header.

You can either cancel the selection event, by not allowing it to be clickable. But that might be a little kludgy implementation, especially for key navigation.

The safer approach, if possible with your data, would be to just move the selection whenever a tree parent node is selected. So it should work like this that if a parent node is selected, either by keyboard or mouse: you expand the node and move the selection to the first child.

This way you can avoid all the paint trickery to hide the selection state.

Comment: +1 But what should happen if a "category element" doesn't have a child?

Comment: I think in that case the selection should automatically be shifted to the last remembered selection, or we should remove selection from the tree if there is nothing that can be selected.

Comment: @WaqasIlyas I agree, ideally it should not be selectable at all, but isn't that what I attempted in the code pasted above?  Like I said, that code doesn't really work.  If there is another way to implement what I'm looking for, let me know.  I suppose I could attach the listener directly to the TreeItem instead of the Tree.

Comment: @DougStephen what you are trying is to fake the non-selected behavior through drawing. I am saying that it would make things easier for you if you ensure that the item actually isn't selected in the tree so that you don't need to hide all the behavior associated with a selected item. As soon as a category element gets selection, move the selection somewhere else or remove it. You should be able to do this in the selection listener alone, and you won't need all the paint/erase event handling.

Comment: @WaqasIlyas Right, but if you look above, in the Selection listener, I immediately set the event detail and event type to 0 (which removes the SWT.SELECTED and SWT.Selection bits, being equivalent to SWT.NONE and SWT.None), and then I set the event's doit to false.  So even commenting out the call to `setRedraw`, that code still doesn't work. I also tried reassigning the selection to `null` and this gives an invalid memory access error on the native code side. Is there another way to block the propagation of the selection event?

Comment: @DougStephen Actually you cannot reliably kill an event using doit or type. The reason is that the listeners are invoked sequentially and if there are listeners registered before yours they would already have run by the time you invalidate the event. You should ideally add a display filter to cancel events like this. But you should also try and handle the selection event by just moving the selection, this is a much simpler approach. I have used it in the past so I can tell you that this can work.

Comment: @DougStephen also I think the selection event occurs post-selection, and if you really want to stop a "selection" on a tree, you need to stop click and keyboard events that result in a selection. This is also never reliable because often on focus (on Windows os) tree get "top" item selected by default.

Comment: @WaqasIlyas Well like I said, simply moving the selection results in a crash on the native code side if the selection is set to null, which is a totally valid argument to set the selection on.  So that strategy might not be the best.  I will look in to using a display filter instead of a listener on the Tree.  But I'm *still* not sure as to how to "cancel the event" if flipping the bits and setting doit to false are just hints. What are you suggesting that I do?

Comment: @DougStephen were you trying `Tree#setSelection(null)`? because null is not valid in this case, you should actually use `Tree#deselectAll()`. Or you can do `tree.setSelection(selectedItem.getItems()[0])` to move selection to a the first direct child.

Comment: @WaqasIlyas Ah, awesome, I'll try that.  I had seen elsewhere that null was okay as an argument to `setSelection`.  Thanks!

Comment: So the strategy of using a display filter seemed to work, in that the Collapse/Expand indicator no longer turns white!  However, the text does, so I still have to attach a PaintListener to paint over the foreground.  Everything else works, so thanks for the help!